# Equivilance of "end = ' '" for beginning of string characther

Tags: python-3.x

In the code `for c in "string": print(c,end = " ")` one gets a new element *after* every string element, is there a keyword argument that instead prints the new element *before* each string element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `print('whatever', c, end='whatever')`?

Comment: `NameError: name 'c' is not defined` this

Comment: you didn't just copy & paste the code I suggested, did you? You used the name `c` in your question, and, obviously, I was referring to it in the comment. So, the whole code would be: `for c in "string": print('whatever', c, 'whatever')`

Comment: Oh right, my bad.

Comment: The problem with `print('whatever', c, 'whatever')` is that it prints a new line for every string (assuming you meant I'd have the for loop in the script) although I wanted something to seperate string characthers, in one line.

Comment: oops, I messed this up: it should be `for c in "string": print('stuff', c, end='stuff')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, (you can see all the keyword arguments to `print` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)), but you can use `sep` to get similar results.  The `sep` string will be printed between each of the positional arguments to `print`.  If our first positional argument is an empty string, then this will effectively print `sep` before each of the positional arguments.

```
print('', *"string", sep=' ', end='')
# s t r i n g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for c in " "+" ".join("string"): print(c, end="")
```

---

```
 s t r i n g>>>
```